# Find duplicates in two DGVs

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview, duplicates, nested-loops

I've spent a lot of time on this and got nowhere. I have two DGVs and trying to compare two columns for the same values, if value in DGV2 is not in DGV1, then that value should go to DGV3. The problem here is logical, but starring in this wrong solution for too long made me incapable to move any further.

It seems to me that whole DGV1 should be searched for first value in DGV2 before `IF`, and all that for every other value in DGV2. I don't know I really need help here.

Thanks.

```
 Dim row As String() = New String() {"", "", "", ""}
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    For A = 0 To DGV2.RowCount - 1
        For B = 0 To DGV1.RowCount - 1
            If GetTextOrEmpty(DGV1.Rows(A).Cells(4).Value) = GetTextOrEmpty(DGV2.Rows(B).Cells(1).Value) Then
            Else
                'PROBLEM : This is going to add row WITH SAME VALUES everytime it's <>
                DGV3.Rows.Add(row)
                DGV3.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = DGV2.Rows(B).Cells(0).Value
                DGV3.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value = DGV2.Rows(B).Cells(2).Value
                DGV3.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = DGV2.Rows(B).Cells(1).Value
                DGV3.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value = DGV2.Rows(B).Cells(3).Value
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

**EDIT : Nevermind. Problem solved with this :**

```
  Dim row As String() = New String() {"", "", "", ""}

    Dim x As Integer = 0
    For A = DGV2.RowCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        For B = 0 To DGV1.RowCount - 1
            If GetTextOrEmpty(DGV1.Rows(B).Cells(4).Value) = GetTextOrEmpty(DGV2.Rows(A).Cells(1).Value) Then
                DGV2.Rows.Remove(DGV2.Rows(A))
            End If
        Next
    Next

    For i = 0 To DGV2.RowCount - 1
        DGV3.Rows.Add(row)
        DGV3.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = DGV2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        DGV3.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value = DGV2.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
        DGV3.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = DGV2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
        DGV3.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value = DGV2.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
        x = x + 1
    Next
```

Comment: Rather than poking into each cell, if you use a DataTable as a DataSource you could more quickly query them for dupes with a few lines of linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit faster with `HashSet` :

```
Dim values = New HashSet(Of String)(From i In Enumerable.Range(0, DGV1.RowCount) 
                                    Select Convert.ToString(DGV1(4, i).Value))

For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DGV2.Rows
    If Not values.Contains(Convert.ToString(r.Cells(0).Value)) Then
        DGV3.Rows.Add(r.Cells(0).Value, r.Cells(1).Value, r.Cells(2).Value, r.Cells(3).Value)
    End If
Next
```